# What is significance of 'navbar-brand' class in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap 3.0.  Can any one tell me what is significance of 'navbar-brand' class in below code?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">Vacation Rentals</a>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="body" class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I would like to know something about magical text 'Toggle Navigation'.  When I am re-sizing my browser I can see a small rectangle on right hand side of the screen, but where is the text 'Toggle Navigation'?
Thanks,
Hemant Shelar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`navbar-brand` class is applied to typical branding logo you see in the top navigation bar.It may just contain a typical image logo or text. Refer to the image below to better understand.[image]

Now coming to the second question.

The class applied to `Toggle Navigation` is `sr-only` that stands for screen reader only.

According to bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), the class is used to hide information used for screen readers.

To know more about accessibility of site for screen readers I would recommend going through the following .
 [Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) and [google web accessibility course](https://webaccessibility.withgoogle.com/course)